# Turing, RAM, or Von Neumann --- which theory/model is the consensus?

Tags: theory

I am not a formal student for CS nor have I ever been, I just want to understand something simple about your field for general knowledge, in plea.

Turing, RAM, or Von Neumann --- which theory/model is consensually accepted to describe how "generally every computer works" (among computer scientists)?

Comment: I’m not aware of a Von Neumann model of computation.

Comment: According to the Church-Turing thesis, your question is all but meaningless, since all reasonable models of computation are equivalent as far as the notion of computability is concerned. If you also care about efficiency, the correct distinction is between classical (deterministic or randomized) computation and quantum computation.

Comment: Hello @YuvalFilmus --- shouldn't this be an answer where you would "tie up" both comments and edit a bit? There are theories to describe all classical/deterministic computing systems and theories to describe quantum computing systems Or is there just one theory who covers both? I got confused.

Comment: Yes, eventually.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus and which, will you say, is the most currently accepted among you computer scientists as such eventual theory?

Comment: It’s a meaningless question. Which is the most accepted theory of City, New York City or Tokyo?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus but why is it meaningless? I mean, if several different researchers have suggested several different theories about how it's to generally describe they way in which computers work, why won't one be more consensually accepted than any other?...

Comment: None of these are theories on how computers work. We get to design computers. We don't need theories to know how computers work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Turing machine and the RAM machine are [models of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation). The Von Neumann architecture is a very high-level [computer architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture). None of these are theories describing how computers work.

Scientific theories describe reality in several different levels, among these:

- Fundamental laws of nature, such as Newton's laws.
- Emergent phenomena, such as consciousness.

There is absolutely no need for a theory describing the fundamental laws behind how computers work, the reason being that humans design computers. We get to set the rules! There might be theories that describe emergent phenomena, such as the structure of social networks.

Close to scientific theories, but not quite the same, are conceptual models such as [seven layer model of networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), which attempts to make sense of complicated edifices engineered by computer professionals. They are not *theories* in the sense that they cannot be right or wrong. They could be more or less helpful at organizing reality into manageable chunks.

---

The Turing machine and the RAM machine are two examples of models of computation, which are used to *define* and to *analyze* computation. According to the [Church–Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis), all reasonable models of computation are equivalent in power, and this includes both of these models.

However, this point of view is very coarse. In practice, one is also interested in various notions of *efficiency*. Another issue is that Church–Turing models are best at describing symbolic computations, not as good at describing numerical computations. For this reason, in practice different models are used in different circumstances, such as:

- [Turing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) were invented by Turing as an intuitive notion of computation, and caught on in the theoretical literature since they are easier to work with than other models. Turing machines are not a good model of how real computers work. They appear in undergraduate classes, are the go-to model in [recursion theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory), and are quite common in [complexity theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory).
- [RAM machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine) are a more realistic model, which is often implicitly used to describe and analyze algorithms. They even appear in certain subareas of complexity theory, such as [fine-grained complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-grained_reduction). However, they don't model all aspects of modern computers, such as bit manipulation and concurrency.
- [Real RAM machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_RAM) are used to describe idealized numerical computations. They are most commonly used in [computational geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry). In some sense this is an example of [hypercomputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation), in that the Real RAM cannot be simulated by a Turing machine, since Turing machines can only handle finite strings (though recursion theory has fixes for that).
- [Boolean circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_circuit) are a theoretical model popular in complexity theory and [theoretical cryptography](https://www.reddit.com/r/crypto/comments/2eb7cg/whats_the_difference_between_theoretical/), and also used to study certain algorithm (under the name *bit complexity*), for example [fast integer multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm). They might be inspired by actual digital circuits, but in practice are probably a poor model for those.
- [Algebraic circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_circuit_complexity) are the "Real RAM" analog of Boolean circuit. They make an appearance when studying [fast matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm), as an example.
- [Quantum circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_circuit) (more popular than [quantum Turing machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Turing_machine)) describe the capabilities of quantum computers. In contrast to classical models of computation (here *classical* means *non-quantum*), which tend to be polynomially related to each other (that is, given an algorithm in one running in time $T$, we can create an equivalent algorithm in another which runs in time at most $cT^c$ for some constant $c$ depending only on the models), quantum computers offer super-polynomial speed-up.

Another basic difference between some of these models is [uniformity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_complexity#Uniformity): are we describing a general algorithm (uniform) or an algorithm for a specific input length (non-uniform)? Sorting algorithms (themselves corresponding to yet another model of computation, [comparison-based computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort)) are typically described as a single algorithm, while integer multiplication circuits are designed on a size-by-size basis.

---

Computer architectures are general principles for designing actual computers. The Von Neumann architecture is an abstraction of the principles used to design some of the early computers, and are still an inspiration today. Unfortunately I am not an expert on this area, so will leave it to others to comment on these.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the usage. For basic formal complexity theory, we usually work with Turing machines. However, RAMs and Von Neumann architectures are a better description for a real-world computer, so some may be more interested in them.

From my personal experience, TMs are the most popular in a CS degree, and in theory in general. I barely saw theoretical usages for RAM, and I never saw any Von Neumann architecture used in theory for computation, but I have seen models that describe a CPU in a specific course that covers that.

Comment: Algorithms are typically analyzed in the RAM model. This includes theoretical work. Other models are used in specific communities, for example computational geometry. Turing machine are only used in complexity theory and undergraduate classes.

Comment: Boolean or arithmetic circuits are also used in complexity theory and for certain classes of algorithms such as integer arithmetic.

Comment: Im still an undergraduate, so I guess this is mainly what I see. Good to know where those things pop up! And yea, I forgot to mention arithmetic and boolean circuits

Comment: @YuvalFilmus "Turing machine are only used in complexity theory and undergraduate classes." And in computability theory (although maybe the argument is that that's math rather than CS).

Comment: Most of the down-to-earth computation is done in high-level languages, which end up compiled to/interpreted on (not really) von Neumann architectures.

Comment: Right, I wouldn’t consider computability theory to be computer science.